# JS changing a class when scroll down to a section doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I have a workable function, which triggers my section and changes it's class to another when it is into view. Here it is:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var top  = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight,
      isVisible = top > document.querySelector('#container').offsetTop;

   if (isVisible) {
     document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class", "h2class2")
   }
});
</script>
```

But I have 3 different sections and for some reason, they change their styles simultaneously after the first trigger. What do I do wrong? Here is the code for 3 different triggers, they are the same, only IDs and classes and variables have been changed:

```
<!-- THE FIRST TRIGGER-->
<script>
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var top  = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight,
      isVisible = top > document.querySelector('#container').offsetTop;

   if (isVisible) {
     document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("class", "h2class2")
   }
});
</script>

<!-- THE SECOND TRIGGER-->
<script>
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var top2  = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight,
      isVisible2 = top2 > document.querySelector('#container2').offsetTop;

   if (isVisible2) {
     document.getElementById('container2').setAttribute("class", "p2class2")
   }
});
</script>

<!-- THE THIRD TRIGGER-->
<script>
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var top3  = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight,
      isVisible3 = top3 > document.querySelector('#container3').offsetTop;

   if (isVisible3) {
     document.getElementById('container3').setAttribute("class", "h3class2")
   }
});
</script>
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Maybe [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) would solve all of your problems and it is much more efficient than scroll listener.

Comment: @Jax-p Thank you very much for your comment. Maybe it indeed will solve it. I am starting to read. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've solved this strange issue by changing triggers IDs to sections IDs, before they were IDs of P and H. It is strange, but after I've changed thriggers IDs to section IDs, it started to work properly.
I mean this line:

```
isVisible = top > document.querySelector('#container').offsetTop;
```

#container should be a section. (in my case it has started to work properly only after this changing)